# Minimum eigenvalue lower bound for recursively defined matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

I have a sequence of recursively defined $R \times R$ real positive definite matrices:

$$
\mathbf{B_{R}} = \begin{bmatrix} 
  R & R-1             & \cdots & 1           \\
  R-1            &  & &            \\
  \vdots            &  & \mathbf{B_{R-1}}  &             \\
  1            &              & &
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and
$$
\mathbf{B_{1}} = [1]
$$

And I know the following numerically: $\frac{1}{4} \leq \lambda_{\min} (\mathbf{B_{R}})$ for $R \geq 2$. How to prove it?

Furthermore, I know this is an asymptotically tight bound, because $\lambda_{\min} (\mathbf{B_{R}})$ is decreasing in $R$ (immediate from Cauchy interlacing) and $\lim_{R \to \infty} \lambda_{\min}(\mathbf{B_{R}}) = \frac{1}{4}$. It would be swell to prove this too.

*Addendum*: initial examples from this sequence:

$\mathbf{B_{2}} = \begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 1                        \\
  1            & 1            \\
\end{bmatrix}$,

$\mathbf{B_{3}} = \begin{bmatrix} 
3 & 2 & 1                        \\
 2 &  2            & 1            \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$,

$\mathbf{B_{4}} = \begin{bmatrix} 
4 & 3 & 2 & 1                        \\
3 & 3 &  2            & 1            \\
2 & 2  & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Is B a Toplitz matrix?

Comment: just looked that up, and no. For example $\mathbf{B_{2}} = \begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 1                        \\
  1            & 1            \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @user619894 see the initial examples from the sequence. It's rather that each descending diagonal is decreasing by one unit.

Comment: So, flipped "L"'s of the same value. What does the eigenvector look like?

Comment: i'll write the eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues in descending order

 $\mathbf{B_2}$ : $v_1 = [-0.8506508 , 0.5257311]$ , $v_2 =  [-0.5257311, -0.8506508]$


 $\mathbf{B_3}$ : $v_1 = [-0.7369762,  0.5910090,  0.3279853]$ , $v_2 =  -0.5910090, -0.3279853, -0.7369762]$, $v_3 = [-0.3279853, -0.7369762,  0.5910090]$

Comment: @MattSamuel yep indeed! i only just caught that myself

Comment: It was an automated comment. I voted to close your question as a duplicate of the question you linked. I believe you can single handedly close it as a duplicate now.